# How to allow non-admin users to create nodes of specified content type?

Tags: forms, nodes, webforms

I've created a content type 'Product' with some fields (like title, cnk, type, ..). I can create a product in my admin theme. But now I would like to create a form that a user (NOT admin) can fill in and submit (content created). How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to **Home > Administration > People**, Permissions tab (URL like http://example.com/admin/people/permissions ). There, find **Node** section.

For each content type you will have 5 permissions that will let you decide who can do what, liek on the screen below:

[image: Screenshot]

Just check "create" for roles that are supposed to be able to create.